# Concurrent.patchPanel not sending data from multiple enumerators - only sends from last enumerator added

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm hoping someone else has used patchPanel to combine multiple enumerators together going down to a client over a websocket. The issue i'm running into is that the patchPanel is only sending the data feed from the last enumerator added into it.

I followed the example from; http://lambdaz.blogspot.ca/2012/12/play-21-multiplexing-enumerators-into.html which is the only reference I've been able to find regarding patchPanel.

Versions; play! 2.1.1 (using Java 1.7.0_11 and Scala 2.10.0)

The web socket method;

```
def monitorStream = WebSocket.async[JsValue] { request =>
  val promiseIn = promise[Iteratee[JsValue, Unit]]
  val out = Concurrent.patchPanel[JsValue] { patcher =>
    val in = Iteratee.foreach[JsValue] { json =>
      val event:Option[String] = (json \ "event").asOpt[String]
      val systemId = (json \ "systemId").as[Long]
      event.getOrElse("") match {
        case "join" => 
          val physicalSystem = SystemIdHandler.getById(systemId)
          val monitorOut = (MonitorStreamActor.joinMonitor(physicalSystem)) 
          monitorOut map { enum =>
            val success = patcher.patchIn(enum)
        }
      }
    }.mapDone { _ => Logger.info("Disconnected") }
    promiseIn.success(in)
  }
  future(Iteratee.flatten(promiseIn.future),out)
}
```

The MonitorStreamActor call;

```
  def joinMonitor(physicalSystem: PhysicalSystem):
    scala.concurrent.Future[Enumerator[JsValue]]
     = {
    val monitorActor = ActorBase.akkaSystem.actorFor("/user/system-" + physicalSystem.name +"/stream")
    (monitorActor ? MonitorJoin()).map {
      case MonitorConnected(enumerator) =>
        enumerator
      }

  }
```

The enumerator is returned fine, and the data fed into it is coming from a timer calling the actor. Actor definition, the timer hits the UpdatedTranStates case;

```
class MonitorStreamActor() extends Actor {
  val (monitorEnumerator, monitorChannel) = Concurrent.broadcast[JsValue]
  import play.api.Play.current
  def receive = {
    case MonitorJoin() => {
      Logger.debug ("Actor monitor join")
      sender ! MonitorConnected(monitorEnumerator)
    }
    case UpdatedTranStates(systemName,tranStates) => {
      //println("Got updated Tran States")
      val json = Json.toJson(tranStates.map(m => Map("State" -> m._1, "Count" -> m._2) ))
      //println("Pushing updates to monitorChannel")
      sendUpdateToClients(systemName, "states", json)
    }
  def sendUpdateToClients(systemName:String, updateType:String, json:JsValue) {
    monitorChannel.push(Json.toJson(
      Map(
        "dataType"->Json.toJson(updateType),
        "systemName" -> Json.toJson(systemName),
        "data"->json)))
  }
}
}
```

I've poked around for a while on this and haven't found a reason why only the last enumerator that is added into the patchPanel has the data sent. the API docs are not of much help, it really sounds like all you have to do is call patchIn and it should combine all enumerators to an iteratee, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PatchPanel by design replaces the current enumerator with the new one provided by the patchIn method.

In order to have multiple Enumerators combined together you need to use interleave or andThen methods to combine enumerators together. Interleave is preferred for this case as it will take events from each Enumerator as they are available, vs emptying one then moving to the next (as with andThen operator).

ie, in monitorStream;

```
val monitorOut = (MonitorStreamActor.joinMonitor(physicalSystem)) 
monitorOut map { enum =>
  mappedEnums += ((physicalSystem.name, enum))
  patcher.patchIn(Enumerator.interleave[JsValue]( mappedEnums.values.toSeq))
}
```

patcher is the patch panel, and mappedEnums is a HashMap[String,Enumerator[JsValue]] - re-add the patcher each time the Enumerators change (add or delete) - it works, not sure if it's the best way, but it'll do for now :)

Comment: Yes you're right, patchPannel only replaces the current enumerator with a new one (I was the author of the original blog post, sorry for my mistake ;) For future readers, I've replaced my old blog post by a new one http://atamborrino.github.io/play/2013/12/25/play-framework-websocket.html (see section "Mixable sub-streams" that relates to the question)